# Changing DATETIMEOFFSET Values globally across the application using culture in C# & ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, timezone, cultureinfo, culture

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that requires to display all datetimeoffset values in a specific timezone according to the logged in user location.

Is there a way to set the culture for the entire application, eg.. `en-us`, `en-GB`, `en-AU` etc. when it loads, and display all datetimeoffset values according to the timezone of the culture setting?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, because culture and time zone are orthogonal concepts.  For example, I might be an English speaking person from New York, but I might be visiting or working in Japan.  If I want my clock to represent local time, I'd set the computer's time zone zone to `Asia/Tokyo` (Mac/Linux) or `Japan Standard Time` (Windows), even though my culture settings would still be `en-US`.

In other words, while .NET does have a way to set *culture* globally for an application (ie. `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`), time zone is not a part of the culture data.

As of latest .NET 8, there is no mechanism for setting *time zone* globally - at least not for the values that are returned from `DateTime.Now`,  `DateTimeOffset.Now`, and `TimeZoneInfo.Local`.

However, .NET 8 introduced the `TimeProvider` class, [which you can read about here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-8#time-abstraction).  Using the example shown there, you can create yourself a `ZonedTimeProvider` and set a particular time zone.  Then in your app, when getting the current time, get it from the provider instead.  The benefit is that you can substitute different providers when running unit tests, or when running in the application in different time zones.

Of course, there's always the traditional way:  Get the UTC time, and convert it to specific time zones as needed using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`.

Comment: Note, `TimeProvider` will help with getting the _current_ time in a particular time zone, but it's not for changing how existing data values are _displayed_.  If ultimately the display is the point you care about, then that is business logic you should handle yourself using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` before you display the value to the user.

Comment: Even if we discount travelling, it doesn't make sense to correlate culture to timezones. `CET` (Central European Time) is observed in [so many](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cet) different countries and cultures. And vice versa, `en-AU` is likely to be used in any of the, uh, [many timezones](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/au) in Australia (I was gonna say 4 or 5, but apparently I need to go back to school).